# When does $E(x|s=\omega)$ increase in $\omega$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $x\sim U[0,1]$ be the "truth", which we observe through an imperfect signal $s$, such that:
$$s=x+\epsilon, \text{ where } E(\epsilon|x)=0.$$

Moreover, the $\epsilon$ is such that $s$ is still in $[0,1]$ (thus, $\epsilon$ is *not* independent of $x$). This is a strong and crucial assumption (thanks for pointing it out!)

I would like to show (or determine under what additional conditions it would hold) that the conditional expectation of the true $x$ given the signal realization is increasing in the signal realization, i.e.
$$E(x|s=\omega)\text{ is increasing in }\omega.$$

It seems intuitive, yet I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim that
$$E(x|s=\omega)\text{ is increasing in }\omega.$$
This is false without any further assumptions. For example, let $\epsilon$ be determined as follows:

Flip a coin (independent of $x$), if heads, set $\epsilon=-2x$, and if tails, set $\epsilon=+2x$.

It is clear that the expectation of $\epsilon$ is zero. However, if $x=c$,
then $s\in\{-c,3c\}$. Moreover, once $s$ has been observed, one deduces $x$, it is
$$x=\begin{cases}-s&\text{if }s<0\\ s/3&\text{if }s\geq 0\end{cases}.$$
Therefore 
$$E(x|s=\omega)=-s$$
for $\omega<0$, which is decreasing.

Even if we assume the random variable $\epsilon$ to be independent of $x$, it is possible to construct counterexamples. For example, let $\epsilon$ be either $-1/2$ or $1/2$, determined also by a coin flip independent of $x$. Then again one determines
$$x=\begin{cases}s+1/2&\text{if }s<1/2\\ s-1/2&\text{if }s\geq 1/2\end{cases}.$$
This is not an increasing function, as there is a jump down at $s=1/2$.

If you choose $\epsilon$ to be a normal Gaussian independent of $x$ then you are right, which would follow from explicitly calculating
$$E(x|s=\omega).$$

PS (hope I am not being rude here) The other answer contains a mistake, I cannot comment on it because lack of reputation. Suppose that $\epsilon$ has a normal distribution. Then we can observe $s=\omega>1$. The other answer then implies
$$E(x|s=\omega)=\omega>1,$$
contradicting that $x$ has the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and is in particular not larger than $1$.

PPS a new counterexample given the new edit of the question:

If $x<1/5$ or $x>1/2$, set $\epsilon=0$.

If $1/5<x<2/5$, set $\epsilon=±1/5$, the sign determined by a coin flip.

So far we are certain that $1/5<s<2/5$ implies that $2/5<x<1/2$.

Finally if $2/5<x<1/2$, then we flip a coin, if heads then
$\epsilon = 4/5-2x$, if tails then $\epsilon = 2x-4/5$.

Then, for $1/5<s<2/5$, we are sure that the coin was heads, and we derive
$$E(x|s)=4/5-s.$$

Although what you say may seem intuitive, it is really not true in general and there are no general theories for it in probability theory that I know of. What you say crucially depends on the choice of error distributions (plural since you have to choose one for each $x$ seperately)!

Comment: Agree on the example. Now, suppose $\epsilon$ is such that $s$ still fits into $[0,1]$ (I should have written it down explicitly in the question). Is this a sufficient assumption for the monotonicity?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is such that $s$ still fits in $[0,1]$ then the distribution of $\epsilon$ must be constantly equal to zero, or it must depend on the value of $x$. I am sure it is possible in that case to construct counterexamples.

Comment: If you want things not to be too complex, then you surely want the distribution of $\epsilon$ to be independent of $x$. Therefore you must allows $s$ to be outside of $[0,1]$. You will also need additional conditions on the distribution of $\epsilon$, see the other counterexample ;)

Comment: No, I *really* don't want $s$ to be outside $[0,1]$. This is crucial, I just forgot to mention it before ;-)

Comment: If $s\in[0,1]$, then the distribution of $\epsilon$ must depend on $x$. For example, if $x=1$, then $\epsilon\leq 0$,  but since $E(\epsilon|x)=0$, you must have $\epsilon=0$.

Comment: So one thing you could do, let $\epsilon$ have the uniform distribution on $[x-1,1-x]$ if $x>1/2$ and the uniform distribution on $[-x,x]$ if $x\leq 1/2$. Then $s$ is guaranteed to be in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in my answer!

Comment: I could imagine multiple $\epsilon$ structures - e.g. some symmetric Beta shifted and scaled (depending on $x$) so that $\mu=0$ and the support is small enough (for $s$ to fit in [0,1]). The question is: given that $\epsilon$ is such that $x+\epsilon\in[0,1]$ (which is already a strong assumption), do we need anything else?
Btw: the bounty is already earned (my mistake with the imprecise question), I just want to continue the discussion :)

Comment: I think there is not general theory that addresses this question, but if the distribution of $\epsilon$ is known then you should be able to calculate $E(x|s=\omega)$ explicitly, to show that it is an increasing function in $\omega$. This should be doable if the distribution of $\epsilon$ is known, and I do not know of a shortcut...

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will keep working on it!